# What is $d$**k**?

Tags: calculus, notation, physics, volume, spheres

Earlier today, I saw $d$**k** $f(k)= $ ... in what I believe was a physics integration problem involving spheres.  I cannot find the original problem.  My question is what $d$**k** means; it is *not* part of an integral, as far as I know.

Comment: More context would be helpful.

Comment: Most likely it did involve an integral but was simply not being written with the integration sign present; such an identity is basically a shorthand for "these two things give the same result when you integrate against them on any (reasonable) subset of the domain".

Comment: That's a great question.  What is d**k?

Answer (score 0):

If what you are seeing is actually $D_k$ $F(k)$ It could be Euler's notation for differentiation. It means the first derivative in respect to *k* of the function $F(k)$.